# MariaDB does not return json for a field with json type

Tags: javascript, node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

im using MariaDB and phpmyadmin to manage my database , i have a field in my table which has the type `json` aka `longtext` but when i do a SELECT `JSON_EXTRACT(field,'$')` i get a response as `'{"name":"string"}'` instead of `{name:"string"}`.
im using sequelize with nodejs to query data.

i've been searching the web and that's the way i came across to parse a json field.

Question:

- is this a wrong way to do parsing? if yes , what is the correct way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return?

Comment: Bill Karwin 10.4.25-MariaDB

Comment: I thought so, since you said "json aka longtext". MariaDB is not MySQL. In particular, their JSON implementations are different, each of them added JSON support after MariaDB forked from MySQL.

Comment: So the only way to parse the field is with JSON.parse after i get a response from db. Thank you

Comment: `{"name":"string"}` is valid JSON whereas `{name:"string"}` is not. Use the JSON.parse to create JavaScript object out of that.

Comment: I think the issue is that there's a JSON data type in MySQL and MariaDB, but not in the MySQL protocol. That is, casting the result to a string is the only way to transmit the result back to the client. Then the client has to deserialize that string into a JSON structure.

Comment: i've been searching and i find this JSON_VALUE() function that mariadb provide. it allows to access to the json stored in the field and select a specific attribute in it, it works as JSON_EXTRACT(). not what i want but it could be useful sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass the input in JavaScript to `JSON.parse()` as @slaakso said. There is no way for Sequelize to determine that you want to automatically do this, despite the fact that you defined the datatype in MariaDB as `JSON`. As @BillKarwin said, this is because there is no true `JSON` type in MariaDB, so Sequelize just thinks it's any old string.